# HTML and CSS button alignment

Tags: html, css, validation

How can I right align a button inside a div without wiping it from the Markup Flow with valid CSS and HTML? Is applying margin-leftthe only way to do this?

I have a structure like this

```
<div class="navContainer">
    <div class="title">
        <span>Nav Titulo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="navContent">
        Nav Conteudo
    </div>
    <button type="button">Enviar</button>
</div>

<div class="navContainer">
    <div class="title">
        <span>Nav Titulo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="navContent">
        Nav Conteudo
    </div>
</div>
```

If I apply `button { float: right }` or `button { position: absolute }` the next `div` will get over the button. It happens that I just want to make the button position at the right side

Comment: Have you tied `float:left;`-ing the `<div>` elements which come before it?

Comment: floating everything on the page is the path of madness...

Comment: You could use `float: right` with a `<br />` tag after the button to force the div to not move up.

Comment: @spinon I don't agree with that solution. Forcing alignment with `<br />` elements is analogous to lining things up with spaces instead of using tab stops in word processing.

Comment: @ghoppe Well everyone is entitled to an opinion. I, to a degree, subscribe to the mindset of what works. And in this case it worked. I am by no means a purist for only css or any of that so not everyone will agree but in the end it works. Maybe some other time we will agree.

Comment: @ghoppe Though I will say that your answer with the css approach was a nice one. It would probably be a cleaner approach as it is less code and not that complex. I will remember that one as I wasn't too familiar with that css.

Comment: @Matt Briggs - You're right! It is impossible to say how first the idea entered my brain, but, once conceived it haunted me day and night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you want to read up on is [clearing](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

if you have floated elements, they go out of page flow, but any element with clear:both will stay in page flow, but not allow anything on either side of it, floated or not.

in practice, adding a clear:both element after you floats makes things work the way you want them to.

Answer (score 1):

```
.navContainer { text-align: right; }
```

Comment: Not quite. This will also right align the div elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt is right. What you need to do is clear the div elements.

```
.navContainer {clear: both}
```

If you want your button aligned at the top of the containing div, you might have to move it before your div element of class "title".